# What's the best way of doing an insert with JpaRepository and checking if it was successful?

Tags: insert, spring-data-jpa

I am working with JPA in Spring and I need to perform inserts of users. The table user primary key is the username.

What's the best way of doing that insert and being certain that the inserted user has a valid username?

At my point of view there are two possible ways:

1. Checking with jpaRepository.exists(id) if the user has a username that was already persisted.
2. Performing a JPA repository insert that throws an Exception or gives any sign if the insert was not completed.

I feel like the first option would lead to unnecessary SQL statements and I don't know how I can perform the second option.

Comment: When I do jpaRepository.save(entity_with_same_primary_key) it doesn't throw any Exception... I know the entity won't be inserted, but I want to know if the entity was or wasn't inserted!

Comment: Do the first option. Creation of new users is not frequent enough to be a performance concern.

Comment: I know, but that's only an example. In fact, the inserted needed will be very frequent.

Comment: "needed will be very frequent." -- unlikely -- and even so the extra query is not a performance issue. Exceptions are not to be used as conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate service class like this for example:

```
public class SomeService {
    private Map<String, User> users;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public SomeService() {
        updateUsers();
    }

    public void updateUsers() {
        users = userRepository.findAll().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getName, u -> u);
    }

    public boolean isNameTaken(String name) {
        return users.contains(name);
    }
    //or
    public User getUserByName(String name) {
        return users.get(name);
    }
}
```

You can call the `updateUsers()` method whenever your repository creates or updates an user so that the map stays up to date.

This should be quite efficient as well if you are concerned about performance.

Comment: if I perform changes to a user, would the database change accordantly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
user=userRepository.save(user);
```

If it inserted successfully then it return the user data with primary key value